# Linear programming - constraining on a maximum of distinct values

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

I'm trying to solve the following linear programming assignment i've been given:

> On a set $\{1,….,N\}$ is defined a discrete cumulative distribution
> function :
>
> $F(i)=y_i,\ \ i=1,...,N$
>
> With $F(i) ≥ F(i − 1),\ \ ∀i = 2,...,N$. Define an other
> discrete cumulative distribution function $G$, which approximates $F$.
>
> $G$ shall assume $n<N$ values (distinct possibles values of $G(i)$ are $n$), and
> shall be defined in a way in which the absolute error (the sum of the
> differences $|F(i) - G(i)|$) is as low as possible.

I can't translate the fact that $G$ have to assume $n$ distinct values into one or more constraints; do i have to introduce logic variables?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is $y$ here?

Comment: Sorry, it's $y_i$ which are the fixed values of function $F(i)$

Answer (score 1):

A natural approach is to introduce binary decision variable $x_i$ to indicate whether $G(i)>G(i-1)$ and then impose cardinality constraint $\sum_i x_i \le n-1$ to enforce at most $n-1$ jumps, equivalently at most $n$ different values.